# How to save file as a reg hive file when saving it in a script?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, export, registry

I have a python script that exports a file but there is a problem with the result. I can't figure out what extension I have to save it as to make it a reg hive file. I am exporting the SAM folder and it's contents from the windows registry with a python script. How can I save it as a reg hive file from a script?

Here is the code:

```
import sys, os
os.system("reg export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM C:\Export.*")
```

I don't know what extension to put after C:\Export.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/330180/96662

Comment: That really improved my understanding of the registry and the difference between exporting and saving. Now I know that I can save it as a hive file by using `reg save` and not `reg export`.